# Wireless network problems

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Okay. This is two problems rolled into one basically.

First of all, my computer suddenly disconnected itself from the wireless network and couldn't reconnect. I looked and the wireless adapter is missing from adapter settings and I couldn't find it in device manager either.

Windows troubleshooter had no help and I can't really re-install the drivers since I don't have internet on that computer.

I would connect it up to ethernet, however the router is far too far away. Any ideas for fixing either of these would be appreciated.

Comment: Just checking: you've rebooted the computer, right? As for the driver, use another PC (with Internet) to look up the driver for your computer's WiFi, download the driver, and copy it to a flashdrive so you can install it on your computer. If you aren't sure which WiFI card it is, grab drivers for a few of them.

Comment: I've rebooted the computer and done a system restore back two weeks. Thanks for the idea about copying drivers to a flashdrive. Why would they have suddenly uninstalled themselves though?

Comment: I really don't know, sorry. System restore (which you already tried) would have been my next suggestion; that should have brought the driver back. Good luck. If you learn anything new, we may be able to help. If it just flat out refuses to work, I'd suggest picking up a new WiFi card - you can get desktop (PCI) ones or USB ones easily enough - or, if that doesn't work, re-installing Windows.

Comment: I purchased a new adapter. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it suddenly vanished completely from device manager, and didn't even go into the unknown devices section, then it could be a hardware problem.

My advice is to use a Linux Live CD, and see if Linux will recognize your wireless adapter. This way you don't have to re-install Windows just to see if it will recognize the wireless adapter.

Here are some Linux distributions you can use to test your WiFi adapter. DO NOT install the OS (unless you really want to, of course), because you don't need to install it to see if it will recognize your adapter.

1) Linux Mint - http://www.linuxmint.com/

2) Ubuntu - http://www.ubuntu.com/

If you end up needing a new adapter, then I would recommend this one:

[http://www.amazon.com/Gigabyte-Bluetooth-Expansion-Components-GC-WB867D-I/dp/B00HF8K0O6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HF8K0O6)